# BrowserRouter Showing blank Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm following a YouTube video tutorial that creates a blog with React and Sanity CMS. Everything went well until I added some code. It keeps showing a blank page. The Video I'm following is using `{ Switch }` but I did some research and found that `{ Switch }` no longer works in V6.

Here's my code:

**App.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Header2 from "./components/Header";
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";
import Blog from "./pages/Blog";
import SinglePost from "./pages/SinglePost";
import Erorr from "./pages/Erorr";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Header2 />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/blog" element={<Blog />} />
        <Route path="/blog/:slug" element={<SinglePost />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<Erorr />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Header.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
export default function Header2() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>hi</h1>
      <header>
        <div className='logo'>
          <Link to="/">
            AndiiCodes Blog
          </Link>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <button>
                <Link to="/blog" relative="path">Blog</Link>
              </button>
            </li>
            <li>
              <button>
                <Link to="/" relative="path">Home</Link>
              </button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </>
  )
}
```

**Blank Screenshot**

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dr6u.png)

**files structure**

[files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfCm7.png)

Console Erorrs:

```
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at App.js:13.
    at App
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
    at Object.useRef (react.development.js:1630:1)
    at BrowserRouter (index.tsx:292:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
```

```
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <BrowserRouter> component:

    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:43763:5)
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "blog",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I rechecked all the files names, I tried to remove `<BrowserRouter>` and all the Routes, the header showed up with no problems. When I'm adding the `<BrowserRouter>` it's displaying blank again.

Comment: Also, are there any errors in the console?

Comment: The only issue I see is two routes for `path="/"`. Try `<Route path="*" element={<Erorr />} />` on the last route. Otherwise, are there any errors in the console?

Comment: well i have a big list of erorrs. how do i post the errors in here..?

Comment: [edit] the post and copy/paste the errors as formatted and readable text snippets.

Comment: Remove the last route and check if it works

Comment: I already tried to remove it.. still didn't work. i added the console erorrs

Comment: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L292 It's failing on this line. React is null for some reason. Can you share your package.json file and how you are running the app?

Comment: i'm running it with 'npm start'

Comment: Can you share the code for `./pages/HomePage`? Think the error might be coming from that.

Comment: I haven't added any code there yet. i tired to comment 'import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage" ' but still didn't work :(

Comment: Can you try commenting out all the routes and see if the error still happens? If that fixes it, you can try uncommenting them one at a time to see which one(s) cause the error

Comment: yes, i already tried but still blank. only works when i comment **<BrowserRouter>** with all the routes.

Comment: And which errors show in the console when you do that?

Comment: `The above error occurred in the <BrowserRouter> component:

    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:43723:5)
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687`

Comment: You are missing `react-router-dom` as a dependency. Add it with `npm i -S react-router-dom@6` and restart the project.

Comment: Please take the [tour]. No one has provided an actual answer here. We don't mark posts [solved].

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `react-router-dom` as a dependency.

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
  "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
  "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
},
```

To add it to your project and update the package.json file run the following in the root directory of the project: `npm i -S react-router-dom@6`

Then restart the project: `npm start`

Comment: `-S` is not necessary as saving is the default behavior for newer versions of npm.

Comment: @Unmitigated Ah, thanks for the info. I'm still on an older version, so it's necessary.